# Lua split string by semicolon

Tags: split, lua

How to split string in Lua by semicolon?

```
local destination_number="2233334;555555;12321315;2343242"
```

Here we can see that multiple times occurrence of semicolon (;) but I need output from above string only before first occurrence.

Tried code :

```
if string.match(destination_number, ";") then
    for token in string.gmatch(destination_number, "([^;]+),%s*") do
        custom_destination[i] = token
        i = i + 1

    end 
end
```

Output :

```
2233334
```

I have tried  above code but newbie to Lua scripting so can't get exact syntax for that.

Comment: `destination_number:gmatch '(%d+);?'`. Replace with `%w` if you need letters too.

Comment: String splitting has been asked and explained many times throughout here and throughout the web.

Comment: If one of the answers below was useful to you then accept it please.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want the *first* occurrence, then this works:

```
print(string.match(destination_number, "(.-);"))
```

The pattern reads: everything up to, but not including, the first semicolon.

If you want all occurrences, then this works:

```
for token in string.gmatch(destination_number, "[^;]+") do
    print(token)
end
```

Comment: What about `a;;c;d` ? Second string is implied to be present and be equal to empty string.  This situation is very frequent in CSV-files

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, sure. The OP needs to define the problem more precisely.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this code will help you:

```
function split(source, sep)
    local result, i = {}, 1
    while true do
        local a, b = source:find(sep)
        if not a then break end
        local candidat = source:sub(1, a - 1)
        if candidat ~= "" then 
            result[i] = candidat
        end i=i+1
        source = source:sub(b + 1)
    end
    if source ~= "" then 
        result[i] = source
    end
    return result
end

local destination_number="2233334;555555;12321315;2343242"

local result = split(destination_number, ";")
for i, v in ipairs(result) do
    print(v)
end

--[[ Output:
2233334
555555
12321315
2343242
]]
```

Now `result` is table which contains these numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here, is easier than you think:

```
for s in string.gmatch("2233334;555555;12321315;2343242", "[^;]+") do
    print(s)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda late, but wondered the substring approach is missing in these answer. So thought of sharing my 2 cents...

````lua
-- utility function to trim the trailing/leading white-spaces
local function _trim(s)
  return (s:gsub("^%s*(.-)%s*$", "%1"))
end

local decoded="username:password"
if decoded == nil then
 decoded = ""
end

local iPos=string.find(decoded,":")
if iPos == nil then
  iPos = #decoded
end

print(iPos)
local username = string.sub(decoded,1,iPos-1)
print("username:=["..username.."]") -- <== Here is the string before first occurance of colon
local password = string.sub(decoded,iPos+1)
password = _trim(password) -- Here is the rest of the string (will include other semi colons, if present)
print("password:=["..password.."]")```
````